# Определение среднего времени прохождения циклов While на Python

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, таймер

Товарищи, помогите пожалуйста недокодеру. Требуется подсчитать среднее время прохождения 10-ти циклов. как видно, после вайла поставил старт таймера, до прибавки счетчика - остановку таймера и соответственно вывод времени одного прохода, но не понимаю, как теперь заполнить массив временем каждого прохода и применить функцию average к массиву со временем, чтобы найти среднее значение всех проходов.

```
if N==3:

while q<10:

    timer_begin = time.time()
    
    mas = [randint(1,4) for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        print(mas[i],sep="")
    print("   ")
    
    mas2 = sorted(mas)
    print('Библиотченая функция - ', mas2)
    print(' ')
    
    timer_end = time.time()
    timer_secs = timer_end - timer_begin

    m=timer_secs
    
    q=q+1

    print ('Затраченное время прохода: %f ms' % (m*1000))

    
mast=[m for y in range (n)]
for y in range(n):
   print(mast[y],sep=' ')
print(' ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас только кусок кода приведен, да и сдвиги нарушены - его не запустить.
Так что вот сокращёный пример с комментарием, как делать:

```
import time
# список для хранения времени прохода
time_list=[]  
q=0
while q<10:
    timer_begin = time.time()
    # 1 сек. ожидания добавлена для примера. В реальном коде не нужна.
    time.sleep (1)
    timer_end = time.time()
    timer_secs = timer_end - timer_begin
    # запоминание среднего времени
    time_list.append (timer_secs)
    q=q+1
# вычисление среднего времени
summa=sum(time_list)/q

print(summa)
```

Comment: В чем у вас сложность-то была? Я думал, что-то сложное, но оно "в лоб" решилось

Comment: Не знаю, как добавить код, в ответ на ваш код, оно запустилось, оно прогнало, но время выполнения каждого прохода многократно возрасло. это норма? дело в том, что следуя заданию, я должен буду увеличивать размеры массива до тысячь

Comment: Это не норма. Но задача выполнена, как поставлено условие:-) Вы же не писали, что вас интересует скорость выполнения. Надеюсь, `time.sleep (1)` вы не вставляли? Он у меня просто для примера.

Comment: Кстати, не вижу, как особо можно ускорить. Разве что сразу список создать нужной длины (если известна), а затем записывать сразу в элемент, а не `append` применять. В каких-то случаях может дать небольшой выигрыш.

Comment: Ура! Принимайте работу:-) - если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Comment: мда, time.sleep убрал. теперь ясно, почему время выполнения увеличилось. Старт секундомера был перед time.sleep. Огромное спасибо. Не хочу показаться наглым, но есть вопрос. Знаете ли вы, как это визуализировать? сколько я голову не ломал, но так и не понял

Comment: Что это значит в данном контексте  - "визуализировать"?

Comment: Хороший вопрос,  которым я и сам задаюсь. Но как я понимаю (и следуя заданию), от меня требуют визуализацию с возможностью включения и выключения. Тоесть нужно как-то отобразить этапы сортировки (скорее всего графически) и возможностью их отключения. Видел пример кода на pygame к примеру, но там мой котёл чуть не треснул. Видел и на какой-то другой библиотеке, там появлялось окно, в котором были столбцы, их размер зависел от элемента массива, запускаешь сортировку и столбцы, которые ракируются, подсвечиваются. Но мне любая помощь пригодится

Comment: Я не любитель визуализаций, так что могу предложить тупо дать две оси (х - номер итерации, у - время) и отмечать на этой плоскости точки. Можно еще среднюю добавить. Для скорости лучше сначала все посчитать, а затем построить за один раз. Сам не делал, но библиотека matplotlib выглядит подходящей. Вот простой пример графика на <https://devpractice.ru/matplotlib-lesson-3-2-plot-layout/>